# Tmux scroll mode: vim keybindings?

Tags: tmux

So if I am in Tmux and a bunch of output came to the terminal, I can scroll through it by pressing:

```
ctrl-b [
```

Now, I have to pick my hands up and go to the arrow keys to scroll up.

How do I map the vim keys in scroll mode?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**Update in 2020**: I don't think anyone should be using any version of tmux below 2, so the concise configs for modern tmux is just

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi V send -X select-line
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'
```

---

**Previous answer**

Unsure which tmux you have. This works for both 1.8 and 2.6, which are the two I'm forced to use.

```
run-shell "tmux setenv -g TMUX_VERSION $(tmux -V | cut -c 6-)"
if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION < 2.4" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
  "setw -g mode-keys vi; \
  bind-key Escape copy-mode; \
  bind-key -t vi-copy v begin-selection; \
  bind-key -t vi-copy V select-line; \
  bind-key -t vi-copy y copy-pipe 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'"

if-shell -b '[ "$(echo "$TMUX_VERSION >= 2.4" | bc)" = 1 ]' \
  "set-window-option -g mode-keys vi; \
  bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send -X begin-selection; \
  bind-key -T copy-mode-vi V send -X select-line; \
  bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'"
```

The relevant section here for hjkl is just `setw -g mode-keys vi` for 1.8 and `set-window-option -g mode-keys vi` for 2.6 (these might even be aliases and work in both versions, not sure). That being said, the `v` and `V` mappings with `xclip` are definitely useful.

Comment: +1. Out of dozens of tmux SO questions I read, this is the first one that differentiates well between versions when it comes to scrolling with vim keys. Exactly the information I needed (to solve a different problem though). Thanks a lot!

Comment: related answer: [Use system clipboard in vi-copy mode in tmux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131011/use-system-clipboard-in-vi-copy-mode-in-tmux#131187)

Comment: To use this answer first install `xclip` package. for Debian based `apt install xclip`

Comment: We're still tied down to tmux 1.8 for some reason, so the different config is useful.

Comment: tmux config is located in ~/.tmux.conf if you want to run these lines when the server starts

Answer (score 10):

To supplement the accepted answer, I found the following `.tmux.conf` lines accomplished most of what I needed:

```
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R
```